# Add repeating events to all weekday that starts with the current day

Tags: fullcalendar

[image: Please refer to this image]

I want my calendar to have the repeating events on weekdays that start on the current day. I already added the events on weekdays but it also adds the events on past dates. events must only be added on current date onwards(weekdays)

```
<script>
    var today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() , new Date().getDate());
    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [  'dayGrid', 'rrule','googleCalendar' ],
            header: {
                left: 'title',      
                right: 'today prev,next',   
        },



      defaultDate: today,
      businessHours: true, 
      editable: true,
        events: 
        [
            {
            title: 'AM 500 Slots',
            start: today, 
            daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]     
            },

            {
            title: 'PM 500 Slots',
            start: today,
            daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]
            }
        ],        
    });

    calendar.render();
  });

</script>
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I used this link  [here](https://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/)  to generate my desired output.